# Create a "hard plastic" material node-setup in Blender and a bump mapping?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders

How can I create a hard plastic material in Blender Cycles?

The exact material I want to create is the following (also the bump mapping):

[image]
[image]

Please add screenshots, and explaining it.
Thanks

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: All the face, with basic materials (just diffuse)

Comment: Tutorial requests are outside the scope of this site. If this is NOT a tutorial request, please edit your question to clearly specify a particular problem that you need help with. As it is, the answer would be "you use glossy and diffuse shaders to make what you want." Help us help you.

Comment: Well, and the bump mapping?

Comment: Do you have a bump texture or want to create one, use a procedual?

Comment: Use procedullar

Comment: Everything online looks so ugly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's another node setup you could try...

[image: Basic waxy plastic material node setup]

It produces a waxy sort of plastic.

Here's what it looks like with some "bump" added:

[image: Basic waxy plastic material with bump / displacement - node setup]

But what's the point of giving you example node setups? If you don't really understand how Cycles' nodes work you won't be able to put together a recipe that conveys the look you want.

**The real answer is: study Cycles a bit more to understand what the nodes do.** Then you'll be able to create the material you are envisioning in your mind.

Once you feel comfortable using all of the common Cycles nodes, I suggest you do some research on PBR with Cycles. It will help you to get even more realistic results. But don't try to jump ahead, because if you don't first understand how Cycles works you will just get even more confused. I am mentioning this as a suggestion for the long term.

Comment: I understand:  diffuse, glossy, glass, transparent, mix shader, add shader, color ramp,  texture coordinate, and that stuff, but i dont understand bump, rgb curves, fresnel, layer wight... What do you recommend me so I can learn properly?

Comment: How do i add the roughtness ndoe?

Comment: the roughness node is a "value" node renamed "roughness". This way you can plug it to different nodes that shares the same value and modify only 1 if needed.

Comment: I recommend you watch at least two tutorials on each of the subjects you mentioned. There is no single tutorial that will explain all of it for you, but there is a lot of helpful information available. You just need to learn to hunt for answers. As for bump, simply plug in a black and white texture into the Material Output's Displacement socket and you will have your bump - you can drop a Math node (set to Multiply) in between to weaken or strengthen the bump effect.

Comment: One more thing... don't forget to *play* with it. Experimentation will teach you a lot.

Comment: I have one problem: the material looks too white

Answer (score 6):

You could try this node setup:

[image]

It produces a result like this:

[image]

Obviously the colors could be modified to your liking. I found the nodes [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?302413-Cycles-Glossy-Plastic-Material).

Answer (score 2):

Oh that's easy. You're looking for the glossy "Improved Perlin" Noise texture. It took me a little bit and I finally mastered it. Here is the node setup I used for the plastic gloss.

[image]

With a few color adjustments to the Diffuse shader which I used a PBR Node Group,you should get something like this.

[image]

If you have any further questions,please feel free to ask me at any time.